# Can this for loop be converted to an IntStream?

Tags: java, java-8

Is there any way the following for loop could be converted to use an `IntStream`?

```
for (int i =1; i<=5; i++)
{
   nums.add(n.nextInt(45)+1);
}
```

I tried as following very simply:

```
IntStream.range(1,5).forEach(nums.add(n.nextInt(45)+1));
```

But it outputs the following error:

> incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to IntConsumer
>      IntStream.range(1,5).forEach(nums.add(n.nextInt(45)+1));

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were missing the parameter of the lambda expression:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,5).forEach(i -> nums.add(n.nextInt(45)+1));
```

Besides, you need `rangeClosed` if you want the indices to go from 1 to 5 inclusive.

That said, there are cleaner ways to use `IntStream` to produce random numbers. For example:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] nums = rand.ints(5,1,46).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. However, when i try it with ints(), it returns this: [I@6ce253f1 ....

Comment: @EosAntigen Try to print the array with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));`.

Answer (score 4):

If `n` is a `Random`, you can use

```
n.ints(5, 1, 46).forEach(nums::add);
```

but if you are actually creating the list rather than adding to an existing list, you can use

```
List<Integer> nums = n.ints(5, 1, 46).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

More than often, you don’t need a dedicated `Random` instance and `ThreadLocalRandom` is sufficient and more efficient:

```
List<Integer> nums = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(5, 1, 46)
                                      .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why `ThreadLocalRandom` is sufficient and more efficient than `Random`?

Comment: @HadiJ In `Random`, all methods are designed to be thread safe. `ThreadLocalRandom`, as the name suggests, provides a state local to your thread which can be updated without thread synchronization. So unless you need reproducible numbers according to a given initial seed, you can use `ThreadLocalRandom`.